present perfect vs past perfect (tense consistency)
Here is a sentence that made me confused. It is from a grammar book and there is no context around it. It is a multiple choice type question.

After returning home from holiday, I realized how much time I ---- just sitting on the beach and thought I ---- more time exploring the area.

The correct answer: had wasted / would rather have spent
One wrong answer: have wasted / might have spent
I think there is no problem with the second part of the question. I wonder whether I can use present perfect for the first part of the question instead of past perfect. If not, why can't I use it? What if the time I have wasted has still some effect on me? Maybe I still occasionaly think of it and feel regretful. Could such a case justify the use of present perfect in this sentence? Is this about tense consistency in a sentence?

Related: Can I use "present perfect" here instead of "past simple"?

(Added as a comment because it's not part of the main question) - Note that would rather have spent and might have spent don't mean the same thing.

[Here is a sentence that confused me.]

The past perfect is used to refer to something that happened before another event in the past.
The speaker's return from their holiday is in the past. The time spent on the beach was during the holiday, so before the return. Therefore, the past perfect is used.
"The time I have wasted sitting on the beach" could be used to refer to all the times in the speaker's life when they have sunbathed instead of sightseeing. But the example sentence is about one particular holiday.

As Kate Bunting describes in her answer, the past perfect is the most likely default answer, because the sitting on the beach comes before the realising.
However I also agree with the general point made by the OP. The present perfect could be used here, suggesting a slightly different meaning:

After returning home from holiday, I realized how much time I have wasted just sitting on the beach...

The choice of present perfect here would imply that the writer is feeling that past time as a present experience. Past perfect points to time wasted then; present perfect would point to it still being a waste now (or at the time of the realisation). It's wasted time that I am never going to get back.
